# Getting 401 response while making get request with bearer token (Python)

Tags: python, request, pytest, web-api-testing

Here is my code---

```
token = APIUtilities()
        auth_token = token.get_token(end_point=App_Config.BASE_URL+"/connect/token",
                                                username="username", password="Password#", client_id="test")

        headers = CaseInsensitiveDict()
        headers["Accept"] = "*/*"
        headers["Authorization"] = "Bearer "+auth_token
        headers["User-Agent"] = "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36"
       

        response = requests.get(App_Config.BASE_URL+"/api/customers", headers=headers)
        assert_that(response.status_code).is_equal_to(requests.codes.ok)
```

I am getting the token but not sure why I am getting 401 error again and again. Please help me to resolve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue is resolved. Above code snippet is fine, problem was with token generation method. It was returning something wrong which I corrected and now code is fine.

Comment: If you have found an answer to your question, consider closing the question by either deleting it or choosing your own answer (or someone else's) as the selected answer.

Answer (score 0):

You are not sending the auth_token in

```
requests.get(App_Config.BASE_URL+"/api/customers", headers=headers)
```

It should be something like :

```
requests.get(App_Config.BASE_URL+"/api/customers", headers={'Authorization': 'auth_token'})
```

Comment: It did not work